# Let $X=U\cup V$ where $U,V$ open and disjoint, then every connected subset $A$ of $X$ is a subset of $U$ or a subset of $V$.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I am asked to prove that if $X=U\cup V$ where $U,V$ open and disjoint, then every connected subset $A$ of $X$ is a subset of $U$ or a subset of $V$.

My way of solution was assuming in contradiction that $A \nsubseteq U$ and $A \nsubseteq V$. hence, $A\cap U, A\cap V \neq \emptyset $. Now notice that $A=X\cap A$, in other words $$A = (U\cap A) \cup (V\cap A)$$
where those are disjoint and non empty sets obviously.
**If** we knew that $A$ is open, we would know that $U\cap A , V\cap A$ are open too, and then we would get contradiction, because we found two disjoint non-empty open sets where their union is $A$, in contradiction to $A$ being connected.

**But** $A$ is not given as an open set!
is there any way to prove it without $A$ being an open set? or $A$ must be open in order for this theorem to be true?

Comment: $U\cap A$ and $V \cap A$ are open subsets of $A$ in the relative topology.

Comment: @geetha290krm Oh, now I understand :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is actually correct. $A$ is a disconected subspace, as both $A\cap U$ and $A\cap V$ are open in $A$ by definition. So you did get a contradiction as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sets $U\cap A$, $V\cap A$. Since these sets are open in $A$, and $A$ is connected, by the definition of connected they cannot both be nonempty. So if $U\cap A=\emptyset$, then $A\subseteq V$, and if $V\cap A=\emptyset$, then $A\subseteq U$. Either way we have the desired result.